# Add attributes to Crow-Entity in Visio 2013 with C#

Tags: c#, interop, shapes, visio

I want to add a shape to an exiting group i dropped by a master-stencil which alread contains around 4 childshapes in Visio 2013 with C#.
In detail I want to add more attributes to a DBEntity.
So far I used the `parent`-Property of the Shape's class, but this always destroys the existing group and makes it non-usable/ ungrouping.

```cs
using VisioApi = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio;


VisioApi.Application application = new VisioApi.Application();
application.Documents.Add(templatePath);
VisioApi.Document crowStencil = application.Documents["DBCROW_M.vssx"];

VisioApi.Master entityMaster = crowStencil.Masters.get_ItemU("Entity");
VisioApi.Master attributeMaster = crowStencil.Masters.get_ItemU("Attribute");

VisioApi.Page page = application.Documents[1].Pages[1];
VisioApi.Shape entityShape = page.Drop(entityMaster, 5.0, 5.0);
VisioApi.Shape attributeShape = page.Drop(attributeMaster, 5.0, 5.2);

// After assigning parent, entityShape isn't grouped anymore
attributeShape.Parent = entityShape;
```

How to do this the right way?

UPDATE: as mentioned in the response, Crow uses Containers - not groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "crow foot" shapes are implemented in Visio 2013 using "containers". So you should use container API to manipulate those. Don't use `Parent` or grouping functions, these are not the ones you are looking for. Use `ContainerProperties` instead, and `InsertListMember` in particular.

Read more about what visio containers are here, and how to manipulate them:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff959245.aspx

Immediate solution for your challenge:

```
// add one attribute to entity shape
entityShape.ContainerProperties.InsertListMember(attributeShape, 0);
```

Mind that M$ may have some plans to revive the old ER diagrams, and this may result in a need to rework of ER-shapes. Means, AFAIU the ER diagram is supposed to be end-user solution, not to be manipulated programmatically - you seem to be crossing a line mere mortals not supposed to cross :)